# breezejs navigation refresh "There is no resourceName for this query"

Tags: javascript, breeze

I have a breeze js navigation property which all loads fine, but I want to refresh the navigation records so I've tried using the following code

```
this.data().entityAspect
  .loadNavigationProperty('PropertyDocuments')
  .fail((reason) => alert("Data refresh failed" + reason));
```

Which gives error **There is no resourceName for this query**

What is the correct method to refresh this?

Navigation property data :-

```
?this.data().getProperty('PropertyDocuments');
__proto__: []
_addsInProcess: []
arrayChanged: {...}
length: 19
navigationProperty: {...}
parentEntity: {...}
wasLoaded: true
[0]: {...}
[1]: {...}
[2]: {...}
[3]: {...}


?this.data().getProperty('PropertyDocuments').navigationProperty
__proto__: {...}
associationName: "PropertyDocument_PropertyForSale"
entityType: {...}
entityTypeName: "PropertyDocument:#DomainModel.Models"
foreignKeyNames: []
foreignKeyNamesOnServer: []
inverse: {...}
invForeignKeyNames: [PropertyID]
invForeignKeyNamesOnServer: [PropertyID]
isScalar: false
name: "PropertyDocuments"
nameOnServer: "PropertyDocuments"
parentType: {...}
validators: []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be caused by not having a 'default' resource name associated with the entityType returned by the navigation property. The resourceName is used by breeze to determine what web service endpoint to call.

Take a look at the metadata for the entity type returned by this property. My guess is that the *defaultResourceName* is null for this type. You can set the defaultResourceName for any type via the MetadataStore.

```
var custType = em1.metadataStore.getEntityType("PropertyDocument");
custType.setProperties( {
    defaultResourceName: "PropertyDocuments"
)};
```

Also see the 'defaultResourceName' description on this page:
http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityType.html